# Use token obtained using R package AzureAuth to Query data

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-rest-api

I am using the following code to get  an access token using *AzureAuth* package in R

```
    library (AzureAuth)
    AuthToken <- get_azure_token("120d688d-1518-4cf7-bd38-182f158850b6",tenant="72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47", app="1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2");
```

However, I don't see any examples on how to use the obtained `AuthToken` in query data from an API?
Appreciate any help!

Comment: Pls choose one response as the answer which is more helpful in your point so that it may help more people.

Answer (score 0):

Pls point out my mistake if I misunderstand your question.

=======================Update=======================

Yes, I found some [documents](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2019/07/01/azurer-available-create-manage-monitor-azure-services-r/) and I followed the sample. And I found that, if I wanna to call graph api, I just need to 'install.packages("AzureGraph")', and with [this package](https://github.com/Azure/AzureGraph) I can reach my goal. And if I need to use AzureR to do some other operations on azure, the ducoment above has offered an example to illustrate how to create a resource group and storage account in AzureRMR, and a registered app in AzureGraph.

===================================================

[Getting started with httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html)

I use this code to get httr get request, and http post request is similar, look up the document above for more details:

```
a <- GET("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", add_headers(Authorization = "Bearer <accesstoken>"))
```

[image]

Comment: @Tinya-wa, I am trying to make the api call programmatically from R. Basically I dont know the syntax how to do it !

Comment: I have updated my answer. And if the document can't meet your requirement, could you pls describe what operations you wanna to do?

Comment: I am using Azure Time Series Insights. Its has got it own API to  query data. I want to extract data into R using those APIs. Its recommended to use POST command. All I am trying to to get an auth key (using my own user credentials) and use that auth token to make a POST command to "https://<GUID>.env.timeseries.azure.com/timeseries/query?api-version=2020-07-31&storeType=ColdStore"; Now I am able to get the Authtoken using AzureAuth package. But there are no examples on how to use in a POST command !

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the syntax. I found it difficult on two counts

1. Syntax for POST command. There are lot of examples for GET command but not many on POST
2. Getting to access_token. However once I started using R Studio, I was able to inspect the object and find the right field. Here is the syntax that worked for me

   res <- POST(EnvironmentFqdnUrl,add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", AuthToken$credentials$access_token)), body = upload_file("body.json"), verbose())
   print(res)